# ancombc2 output fmt length exceeds maximal format length 8192

Tags: maxlength, fmt

After filtering down dataset based on sequencing batch and specific T6 timepoint, I tried to do an ancombc2 comparison between 2 groups on a Phylum tax level:

```
out_phylum_S2022_T6 <- ancombc2(
    data = tse_S2022_T6,
    tax_level = "Phylum",
    fix_formula = "responder", 
    p_adj_method = "holm",
    pseudo = 0, pseudo_sens = TRUE,
    prv_cut = 0, # no prev filtering necessary anymore 
    lib_cut = 0, 
    group = NULL, 
    struc_zero = FALSE, 
    neg_lb = FALSE, 
    alpha = 0.05, 
    global = F,
    pairwise = FALSE,
    dunnet = FALSE,
    trend = FALSE,
    n_cl = 1,
    verbose = TRUE,
    iter_control = list(tol = 1e-5, max_iter = 20,verbose = FALSE),
    em_control = list(tol = 1e-5, max_iter = 100),
    lme_control = NULL, mdfdr_control = NULL, 
    trend_control = NULL
)
```

Following output is generated in console:
*Error in { :
task 1 failed - "'fmt' length exceeds maximal format length 8192"*

The same analysis was done on tax_level="Genus" and tax_level="Species" without errors.
Is there any specific solution for tax_level="Phylum"?

BR,
Dora